# Why are F# exceptions generally not suffixed with 'Exception'?

Tags: exceptions, f#, idioms

In .NET, it is idiomatic to suffix exception types with `Exception`. But most, if not all, sources I have seen for custom exception types in F# don't follow this idiom.

Most seem to use the suffix `Error`.

From [F# For Fun and Profit](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/exceptions/)

```
exception MyFSharpError1 of string
exception MyFSharpError2 of string * int
```

From [Microsoft Documentation](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aHDyEGECgZ5QJ%3amsdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233190.aspx%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=dk)*

```
exception MyError of string
```

The book 'Expert F# 3.0', co-authored by Don Syme, has an example that doesn't even seem to follow any idiom:

```
exception BlockedURL of string
```

Why don't custom exceptions in F# follow the standard idioms for .NET? Is it because of the OCaml heritage?

* Link is to Google cache, as I cannot connect to MS at the time of writing.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're too quick to generalize based on just a few data points. There is some diversity there, but on the whole you're still more likely to see *Exception than anything else, in my experience at least.

As for why there is more variation out there, I think there are a couple of different factors at play:

- F# is a .NET language and uses the same standard libraries which follow the *Exception convention. Also, a great number of users comes to F# from C#, and they're likely to use what has worked for them so far. Look at [github results](https://github.com/search?q=Exception+language%3AF%23&type=Code&ref=searchresults), there's plenty of *Exceptions there (admittedly, some *Errors as well).
- You seem to be correct about OCaml heritage - again, going by [github results](https://github.com/search?p=9&q=exception+language%3AOCaml&ref=searchresults&type=Code), it's a widespread practice to name exceptions without any suffixes. The few *Exceptions I saw came from .fs files classified as OCaml.
- C# has its golden standard code guideline that everyone seems to follow unanimously; I don't think F# had anything comparable from the start. Now there's [F# Component Design Guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/fsharp-design-guidelines-v14.pdf) document from FSF, and it actually advices to follow the .NET *Exception style.
- Previous point is further aggravated by the fact that compared to C#, there's very little tooling support for F#. There's no Resharper/StyleCop/FxCop for F# to enforce a code style for you (heck, there's not even a "Rename" out of the box in VS!).

Comment: [The guidelines you mention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042) for C# are not actually C#-specific at all, they apply to all .Net languages (including F#).

Comment: They are pretty C#/VB.NET-centric even if it doesn't say so on the tin. I assure you that following some of them in F# would lead to hilarious results. And .NET hosts many other languages where they'd be out of place as well.

Comment: I do agree that keeping to those guidelines on a public interface level would be a nice gesture if you're writing an F# component intended to be consumed by clients written in other languages (read: C#). This does include naming exceptions your code might throw accordingly.

Comment: Those guidelines apply *only* to the public interface level. They're not meant to tell you how to write your implementation (for example, they explicitly don't say how to name private fields).